# picking a file from the memory of iphone?

Tags: iphone

i am making a client server program for iphone communication with the sever i want to know

that how can  i pick a file (jpg, 3gp, bmp or some word document ) from the memory of  the

iphone and send it to the server please explain in some detail as i m new in iphone

programming and give some code for it if possible, and how can i convertv an adobe reader and

msword compatible file to jpg file.

Comment: this is not write my code for me site! show us your code first!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow down there buster.

There is no "memory of the iPhone." You'll have to get that file in somehow besides a traditional file system. There are ways to send files to other apps… check the docs. To start with, why don't you bundle in a couple files with your .app to test with.

Once you have the file, use something like the `ASIHTTPRequest` library (google it) to send it to the server.

Clear?